# Kinect Data Via router to Host PC

Tags: ros, kinect, icreate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on an irobot create platform using a kinect to do some
basic navigation.
However I don't want to use an onboard computer to do the processing.
I wanted to do the processing on another host computer by accessing
the data through a wireless router housed on the create.
So is it possible to run ROS on this host computer and accessing the
robot via router

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9253/kinect-data-via-router-to-host-pc/) by [Dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/222/dev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-03-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Except for the possibility that your communication channel isn't suited for such large data transport (as mentioned by William) it's perfectly possible to run some nodes on an external machine. You can distribute this from one launch file by using the [machine tags](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/machine). It helps to have your SSH-keys set-up correctly.
You can find an example of such a file in our [AR_pose_demo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ar_pose_demo) package. In the ar_pose_kb_double_distri launch file, I'm launching camera's with connected image processing over different computers and only the results are streamed over the Wifi channel.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe wireless streaming of Kinect data is going to be a possible solution with out an on-board computer.  In general the Kinect produces quite a lot of data, to the point that you have to decimate the information it is sending considerably to send between two computers, especially over WiFi.  If you had an on board computer that could process the data down to a small enough size you could send it over WiFi to another computer.

For on-board processing, you have a few options:

1. x86 based computer:

- [Fit-pc2](http://www.fit-pc.com/web/)
- [Other embedded motherboards](http://www.mini-box.com/s.nl/sc.8/category.15/.f)

2. Embedded processor

- [EROS Embedded ROS](http://www.ros.org/news/2010/10/embedded-project-for-ros-eros.html)

You can probably manage to adjust the quality settings on the Kinect and do some preprocessing on the on-board computer to make wireless streaming a reality, but with an on-board computer I would say it is next to impossible to get the Kinect data remotely.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2011-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1